# Running PHP in HTML Files on NginxProxy Centos

Tags: nginx, php, centos6

I have a ngnixproxy server on Centos 6.0.

Wordpress and php files are running fine.

But I have a static site with an html file with php code in it.

The code is not working and the server is downloading the html file instead.

I have this in .htaccess file

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Fastcgi and php are installed properly.

Any advice?

thanks

Comment: anything in error log?

Comment: I'd advise to just rename to `.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by replacing

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

with

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm
```